# Convert list of payloads with a property List<String> to HashMap<String, Payload)

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I've a list of payloads and a payload looks like

```
Payload {
 public int id;
 public String name;
 public String foo;
 public List<String> list;
}
```

now I want this to a HashMap where the key is a value of the `list` property, like

```
payloads = [
 {id:45, name:"Alfred", foo:"bar", list:["AAA", "BBB"]},
 {id:2, name:"John", foo:"various", list:["CCC", "DDD"]},
 ...
];
```

to HashMap<String, Payload>

```
map = [
{key: "AAA", value: {id:45, name:"Alfred", foo:"bar", list:["AAA", "BBB"]},
{key: "BBB", value: {id:45, name:"Alfred", foo:"bar", list:["AAA", "BBB"]},
{key: "CCC", value: {id:2, name:"John", foo:"various", list:["CCC", "DDD"]},,
{key: "DDD", value: {id:2, name:"John", foo:"various", list:["CCC", "DDD"]},,
]
```

I've tried `.flatMap()` and own mapping collectors but nothing worked. If I research I only find solutions to group by flat payload objects, like Payload.name nothing if the group key is in a List of these objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want if multiple payloads have the same value in the `list`? You either have to decide which `Payload` to pick, or map to a list of payloads.

Comment: Hello, sry I've forget to tell, all values of the List<String> are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume given `List<Payload> payloads` with stream API it could be done as follows:

```
    payloads.stream().flatMap(payload ->
            payload.list.stream().map(listValue -> Map.entry(listValue, payload))
    ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

With Java 8 use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry()` instead of `Map.entry()`

Although, it may be worthy to use @Jorn approach

Comment: Map.entry() not exists in Java8 but you helped me a lot to understand how I could solved it. Thx.

Comment: @Dominic Have updated the answer for java 8. Upvote would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd probably just go for the simple, imperative approach:

```
Map<String, Payload> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Payload payload : list) {
  for (String value : payload.list) {
    map.put(value, payload); // you may want to check this returns null
  }
}
return map;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid nested fors and preferred a method with lambda. If its possible.

Comment: Not a good requirement. Your code will be a lot clearer and simpler in that form rather than as streams plus lambdas

Comment: @Dominic Sure it's possible. But you should always prefer to go for the more readable approach. Compare this to the accepted answer, and try to see which is easier to understand and maintain.